# Setting up OGRE in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ogre

Using [this](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Setting%20Up%20An%20Application%20-%20Visual%20Studio) tutorial I managed to install & set up ( partially at least ) ogre.
The only problem seems to be that VS can't find the OGRE include files (.h).

C/C++ - General - Additional include directories looks like:

```
$(OGRE_HOME)\include
$(OGRE_HOME)\include\OGRE
$(OGRE_HOME)\include\OIS
$(OGRE_HOME)\include\Samples\Common\include
$(OGRE_HOME)\include\boost
```

I also tried running

```
notepad.exe "%OGRE_HOME%\include\OGRE\OgreCamera.h"
```

to check if the OGRE_HOME is set correctly and it is.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In VS settings, in additional directories you need to add an include directory pointing to your OGRE includes. I'm writing it from top of my head so I don't remember the exact place but I believe you'll find it.

If you still have problems I can check the exact place when I get back to home.

AFAIK: OGRE_HOME works for command line tools and compilers but not for VS itself.